# Accept Text/Plain format as if it was JSON so the model can be parsed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an API which takes a specific type as input but the front-end sends request in `text/plain` rather than `application/json`.

How can I make it so that the API accepts the data as if it was JSON automatically?

```
[Route("GetNotification")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetAllNotifications([FromBody]GetNotificationsBySearchVm Search)
{
    try
    {
        GetAllNotificationsVm result = notificationBusiness.GetAllNotification(Search);

         return Ok(result);                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This is the body of the request in `text/plain`:

```
{
    "index":1 ,
    "size": 10,
    "userID":26,
    "appID": null
}
```

When ran, I get this error:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type `System.String` to type `xxx.GetNotificationsBySearchVm`.

Comment: Do you have any control over the client's request headers? If so, the appropriate solution would be to specify the content-type as `application/json` in the request. Otherwise, the best solution I know of is to have the `Search` type be a string and manually deserialize it into your `GetNotificationBySearchVm` type

Comment: Thank ypu very much ,i tried this and it works well , but i need something more general to not make those steps in each Api.